# Data Mismatch error while using the Update query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am using the Update query inside VBA to Update one particular column.

But I am getting the Data Mismatch in criteria expression error. Please find below the code.

```
Public Function UpdateDistinctColumnFRNumberBasis()

MergedInvoiceFile = "\test.xlsx"

StrInvoiceNumber = "010541-01"

FRSparepartNumber = "FT99999000006"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual

Application.EnableEvents = False


Dim objConn As Object

Dim objRecordSet As Object

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set objRecCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

Set objRecCmd_Update = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objConn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & MergedInvoiceFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;""")

strSQL = "Update [Tabelle1$] SET [Distinct] = 'Distinct' Where ([RECHNR] ='" & StrInvoiceNumber & "' AND [TEILENUMMER] = '" & FRSparepartNumber & "')"
    
objConn.Execute strSQL


objConn.Close

Set objConn = Nothing

Set objRecCmd = Nothing

Set objRecCmd_Update = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: This is the Query : Update [Tabelle1$] SET [Distinct] = 'Distinct'  Where ([RECHNR] ='010541-01' AND [TEILENUMMER] = 'FT99999000006')

Comment: This will fail if `[RECHNR]` or `[TEILENUMMER]` is a numeric  field.

Comment: The column [TEILENUMMER] contains numeric and alphanumeric values. I have added a dummy value whose formatting is "general" in the first row of column [TEILENUMMER] so the SQL consider whole column values as "general"

Comment: Cant we make a query in which whether a column contains , numbers , string or alphanumeric it will take it.

Comment: Your query is correct. As this is Excel, perhaps it reads the values wrongly.

Comment: What would be the solution then?

Comment: Don't know. Would need to debug the data. Try with some simple and straight values like `abc` and `123`.

Comment: But ultimately I have to work with this live data

Comment: Yes. But to correct, you must know what (and why) to correct.

Comment: I dont know why it is not working